# Unable to block Linkedin.com

Tags: networking, internet, hosts

I needed a break from wasting time on LinkedIn and Twitter, so Iappended following to `/etc/hosts` file on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
127.0.0.1 twitter.com
127.0.0.1 linkedin.com
```

This blocked Twitter but not LinkedIn. Then I installed Firefox extension BlockSite to block it, but that didn't work either.

What is the issue behind LinkedIn? How can I block such websites?

Comment: second line is incorrect, there should be domain name, without path. Remove `127.0.0.1 linkedin.com/feed`. Btw, I have blocked linkedin.com by provider :)

Comment: "by provider" What does that mean?  Please explain your solution. I have tried all these URLs for linkedin.com one by one.

Comment: Multiple entries in `/etc/hosts` with the same IP address confuse the system. `127.0.0.1 localhost twitter.com linkedin.com in.linkedin.com` is the right way.

Comment: I suggest that you try: `0.0.0.0 linkedin.com` and for all other sites you wish to block.

Comment: While Twitter uses only `twitter.com`,  LinkedIn uses more than one domain. For example, it shows `www.linkedin.com` in my browser's address bar when I connect to it. You have to cover each separate domain name in `/etc/hosts` (`linkedin.com` won't handle `www.linkedin.com` or anything else).

Comment: Hi, @ManasveeKumar, have you succeed with this task?

Comment: Hi,  task completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server name is `www.linkedin.com` and `linkedin.com` is a redirection. So I would prefer to use directive as the follow in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 www.linkedin.com linkedin.com
```

Also you should **empty the browser cache**. ([Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/773635/block-network-access-to-a-domain-ubuntu#comment1004970_773636)) You could use also `0.0.0.0` instead the loopback interface, I think there is no [difference](https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/) in this case.